# No refresh when clicking a button (dropdown)

Tags: jquery, html, contao

Thank you Ganesh "onclick ="return false;" works :D

So i made a onclick dropdown menu with this tutorial: [clickable dropdown menu](http://toddmotto.com/flawless-clickable-drop-down-navigation/).
The problem is that when i click the button to open the dropdown menu the website refreshes.
How can i change that?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="menuebutton">
  <ul class="no-js">
    <li>
      <a href="" class="clicker"><img src="files/KH-Homepage/menue_button.png" alt="Icon"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$(function () {
  $('#menuebutton > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
  $('#menuebutton .js ul').hide();
  $('#menuebutton .js').click(function(e) {
    $('#menuebutton .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('#menuebutton .js ul').is(':visible')) {
      $('#menuebutton .js ul', this).slideUp();
      $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

I tried it with chrome, firefox, and my android browser

Comment: Show us your code. D:

Comment: the code is the same as in the tutorial

Comment: which browser and version you are using?

Comment: use onclick ="return false;"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent default action of anchor:

```
$('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Rest of your code here
});
```

Comment: now the CSS fallback activates :/

$(function () {
$('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $('#menuebutton > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
  $('#menuebutton .js ul').hide();
  $('#menuebutton .js').click(function(e) {
    $('#menuebutton .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('#menuebutton .js ul').is(':visible')) {
      $('#menuebutton .js ul', this).slideUp();
      $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
});